# Where is the executable `b2` for installing boost from sources?

Tags: boost

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 as my OS, and I have followed every tutorial out there that claims to teach me how to install boost from sources, but all these tutorials magically use `b2` to finally install everything after calling `./bootstrap.sh`. There are no binaries named `b2` generated after running `bootstrap.sh` nor there seems any packages I can separately install using `apt-get`. I tried searching everywhere, but the only piece of information I can get is that `b2` is supposed to be a building system only for boost. So how do I acquire this binary? Why aren't there any tutorials telling me how to get it? I might be getting a little crazy here...

Comment: Works for me. Post the output of `booststrap.sh`. Do `find -name b2` to see where `b2` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
./bootstrap
./b2
./b2 install
```

Please you look this :http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#easy-build-and-install